# Rolling a loaded die and the probability of getting the third six on the 7th roll

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A die is loaded in such a way that the probability of the face with j dots turning up is proportional to $j^2$ for j = 1,2,3,4,5,6. What is the probability of getting the third six on the 7th roll of this loaded die?

I came across this question while reading a book on probability. I initially thought that the answer is ${(\frac{1}{6})}^3$ x $(\frac{5}{6})^4$ because 6 occurs 3 times and 4 times not, but then as I look at the answer keys I was wrong. Can you please explain why the answer to the question is 0.1239?

Comment: The answer cannot be $0.1239$. The sum of the weights is $91$, which has no factors of $2$ or $5$, so the result can't be a terminating decimal. Perhaps this is the answer rounded to four decimal places?

Comment: Because the die is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The die is loaded, so the probability of a single die rolling a six is $\frac {36}{91}$.

[Because $1/91$ is the constant of proportionality determined by the sum of weights (i.e. $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{6} j^{2} = 1^2{+}2^2{+}3^2{+}4^2{+}5^2{+}6^2 = 91$) and $36$ is the weight for result of a single die to be `6`.]

Further, the probability of obtaining the third six on the seventh roll is the probability six occurs exactly twice *somewhere* within the first six rolls, and once on the seventh: $$\dbinom{6}{2}\dfrac{(36)^3(55)^4}{91^7}\approx0.1239{\small 3}$$

Answer (score 1):

The probability that a single toss is a $6$ is $p=\frac{36}{91}$.

After six tosses, the probability of having exactly two sixes is:

$$\binom{6}{2}p^2(1-p)^4$$

So the probability that you get the third six on the seventh roll is:

$$\binom{6}{2}p^3(1-p)^4=\frac{15\cdot 36^3\cdot 55^4}{91^7}\approx 0.12392524$$