# A die is loaded so that the probability of a face coming up is proportional to the number on that face. Find V (X) and D(X).

Tags: probability-theory

A die is loaded so that the probability of a face coming up is proportional to the number on that face. The die is rolled with outcome X. Find V (X) and D(X).
How would you find the Expected value E(x) and the variance V(x) for this problem?

For this problem, I knew that the probability for each outcome would be x/21. And I knew that X=1,2,3,4,5,6 so I took the expected value of 1× (1/21)+2× (2/21)+3×(3/21)+4×(4/21)+5×(5/21)+6×(6/21) and got 3, then I tried to find the variance by using V(x)=E(x^2)-(E(x))^2=12, but the answer was 3/4 for V(x).

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  the condition is $P(n)=cn$ for some constant $c$ and $n\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  Can you solve for $c$?

Comment: Welcome to maths SE. You should propose the beginning of a solution... because it is a rather easy problem. The principle of Math SE is to show that one has worked on the subject and has identified blocking points.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1825705/265466

Comment: Check your expected value first. It does not equal to 3. And the answer $3/4$ for the variance is incorrect too.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that we are looking at six sided dice.

$P(1)= a, P(2)= 2a\cdots P(6) = 6a $

The sum of the probabilities equals 1.

$(1+2+3+\cdots +6) a = 1\\
21a = 1\\
a = \frac 1{21}$

$E[X] = \sum_\limits{n=1}^{6} n P(n) = \sum_\limits{n=1}^{6} \frac {n^2}{21} = \frac {13}{3}$

$V[X] = E[X^2]- E[X]^2  = $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{6} \frac {n^3}{21} - (\frac {13}{3})^2\\ 21 - (\frac {13}{3})^2$